# count number of non-NA columns in a grouped_df dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, janitor

I am trying to create a column in my `.df` that gives a value on the number of (non-NA) columns. This is straightforward in instances where the data is not grouped, as I can use `ncol()` or `dim(df)[2]`. My problem is trying to use either of these functions on groups within the df, especially as once I group my data some columns become empty (which I then remove, and so column size changes across different groupings).

Example:

```
data(iris)
iris$fake.dat1 <- rnorm(1:50) 
iris$fake.dat2 <- rnorm(1:50)
iris$fake.dat3 <- rnorm(1:50)
# make some groups be all NA for some columns
iris$fake.dat1[iris$Species == 'setosa'] <- NA
iris$fake.dat2[iris$Species == 'setosa' | iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- NA
```

I want to add a column to my data frame that would count the number of non NA columns for each Species. I used the function `remove_empty_cols` in the janitor package.

So far, I've tried:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  remove_empty_cols(.) %>%
  mutate(num.col = ncol(.))
```

This gives a column of all eights. If I filtered the data to each group then above appears to work:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(Species == 'setosa') %>% 
  remove_empty_cols(.) %>% 
  mutate(num.col = ncol(.))
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if it's possible for variable which have `NA` for some—but not all—values within a group, and how you want to count those rows or groups.

If you just want the number of non-`NA` values for each row, the solution is pretty simple:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# add partial NA column
iris <- iris %>% mutate(fake.dat3 = ifelse(fake.dat3 < 0, NA, fake.dat3))

iris1 <- iris %>% mutate(num.col = rowSums(!is.na(.)))

table(iris1$num.col)
#> 
#>  5  6  7  8 
#> 21 50 50 29
```

If you want a count of the columns for each group that have some non-`NA` values, it's a little more complicated:

```r
iris2 <- iris %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>% 
    mutate(num.col = map_int(data, ~sum(map_lgl(.x, ~!all(is.na(.x)))))) %>% 
    unnest()

table(iris2$num.col)
#> 
#>  5  6  7 
#> 50 50 50
```

If you want a count of the columns for each group that don't have *any* `NA`s, change `all` to `any`:

```r
iris3 <- iris %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>% 
    mutate(num.col = map_int(data, ~sum(map_lgl(.x, ~!any(is.na(.x)))))) %>% 
    unnest()

table(iris3$num.col)
#> 
#>  4  5  6 
#> 50 50 50
```

For the original data, all approaches will return identical results, but as you can see, on real data likely will not.

Comment: It was the second option - and it works perfectly, so thank you!

Comment: This currently returns an error ```Warning messages:
1: All elements of `...` must be named.
Did you want `data = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)`? 
2: `cols` is now required.
Please use `cols = c(data)` ```

Comment: Yeah, they changed the way they want you to use the interface to `nest()`, though it still works fine. To silence the error, you could change it to `iris %>% nest(data = -Species)` or equivalent.